# Why does error_log() always send exactly 3 emails?

Tags: php, error-log

I'm using the error_log() function like so:

```
error_log($errorstring, 1, 'myemail@gmail.com');
```

And it works fine, but every single time it is executed I get exactly 3 copies of the same email spaced about 1 or 2 seconds apart.  There is no loop or anything that it's in, this is simply to notify me of a failed login attempt, so it is only called once before it die()s.

Anyone have any bright ideas on this?

EDIT: Sorry forgot to mention, this is in PHP using the error_log() function.

EDIT2:  I have switched to using the custom error handler found here:

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/errorhandler.html

What I have discovered is that while MySQL errors generate only a single email as intended, non-MySQL errors generate the three emails.  It's always three... never more or less, and they are spaced anywhere from 0 to 2 seconds apart, based on the timestamp sent in the emails.

Anyone have any other ideas why in the world this would be happening??

Comment: Which language are you using? Is this for php?

Comment: Yes PHP, edited the question for clarity... thanks!

Comment: Have you tried enabling `ignore_repeated_errors` in php.ini or using `ini_set`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried:

`ini_set('ignore_repeated_errors' , 1);`

and it had no effect at all.  =(

Comment: Nobody has any other ideas?  I really don't want to go live with this method of sending me errors, if it's going to result in triplicate emails every time...

Comment: Can you post the headers of all three emails you receive? (Or even better the headers of the first email, then a diff of that for each of the other two emails.) (I'd also be interested to see the headers for the mysql errors email you get; I'm curious why just that is behaving differently.)

Comment: What if you generate this error manually from the most minimalistic script possible? Will you get 3 emails in that case?

Answer (score 0):

[PHP MANUAL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

```
error_log($errorstring, 1, 'myemail@gmail.com',string $extra_header);
```

`1` message is sent by email to the address in the destination parameter. This is the only message type where the `fourth parameter`, extra_headers is used.

`extra_headers`

The extra headers. It's used when the `message_type` parameter is set to `1`. This message type uses the same internal function as mail() does.

Comment: Very good.  Now, exactly how does that quote from the docs answer the question?